# Dokku not deploying my PHP app

Tags: php, dokku

I am trying to deploy a PHP app to dokku. When I push the code, or run `dokku ps:rebuild app` the build process gets all the way to the end, and says

```
=====> Application deployed:
   http://app.example.com
```

However, visiting the address does not serve up the app and if I run `dokku ls` I get the following output:

```
-----> App Name   Container Type    Container Id    Status                   
       app        NOT_DEPLOYED      NOT_DEPLOYED    NOT_DEPLOYED
```

I have other (django) apps already running fine, so I know dokku is working.

I'm running on dokku 0.5.4.

This is the Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf
```

This is the .env file:

```
export BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git
```

There is a composer.lock file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a chat with a colleague, in this situation you need to set the scale for the app. It's often caused by pushing the app to dokku before running `dokku apps:create <app>`. (Although I don't think that was the case for this app, it was probably something similar.)

So if after you push the app and dokku initially says deployed but the app is not actually deployed, run this command:

```
dokku scale <app> <proc=amount>
```

Where `<app>` is the name of your app, `proc` is the process type, in my case it was `web`, and `amount` is the number of processes you require, in my case it was `1`. So my command looked like:

```
dokku scale app web=1
```

(This solution was mostly taken from [this dokku elastic search issue](https://github.com/jezdez-archive/dokku-elasticsearch-plugin/issues/14#issuecomment-191244904).)